# Why does the astable multivibrator using transistor not work when I use the same value of resistance for the collector of both the transistors?

Tags: transistors, analog, oscillator, proteus, multivibrator

The circuit shown in the figure does not run even in proteus. But when I change the collector resistance above 1.43k of one of the transistor, the circuit starts working. What's the reason behind such operation? Please help me with proper explanation.
And also if I use DC supply instead of battery, the circuit does not work by replacing R1 with 1.5k as well.
[image]

Comment: 12V is excessive unless you use 5V zeners or 2 LEDs across Vbe's in series to prevent exceeding VEB.  Rb/Rc =100 is demanding hFE >100 in order to saturate (approx) under startup conditions.

Comment: Not familiar with Proteus, but in LT Spice requires that the schematic has a GND symbol attached to a net somewhere.

Comment: Up to how much can we make the oscillation frequency using 1uF capacitor? When I used .1ohm resistor, both the outputs become 11V always without oscillation.

Comment: Where is  ground?

Answer (score 4):

You can usually cause the simulation to work okay if you use the *initial conditions* card, **.IC**, in your schematic project to set an unusual node voltage as a starting point.

(You could also add a starting pulse using a PWL current source and a diode, for example. But that's more complicated to do.)

That said, your specific schematic does run under LTspice without any special additions:

[image]

I seem to recall Mike saying he used some tricks in the simulator to encourage some astable multivibrators and ring oscillators to start up more consistently, without having to pay a price. But I don't recall anything about the trick. Whatever it is, it appears to work as shown above.

But for simulators generally, as well as LTspice, you can use the **.IC** card like this:

[image]

Note that in this case **OUT1** is pulled high at the start. That helps begin the oscillation.

Various other ideas can be used. In some situations, like this one, you could make \$R_2\$ a little bit different from \$R_3\$ and see if that helps out. But I think the **.IC** card is probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

A simulator has identical components, so both transistors conduct equal amount and there is no imbalance to start the oscillation.

In real world, non-idealities of components means that always one of the transistors will conduct first and the oscillation starts.

Therefore, to simulate oscillators, the non-idealities must be edited in to the components by changing the component values for example.

Comment: I need to change the resistance value ba atleast 400ohm of R1 to make the circuit running. To make the circuit non ideal if I change its value by just 10 or 20 ohms also, I believe it should work but it does not. So that made me to think there may be more reason. THe circuit may not work in real world as well if such difference need to be maintained for running it?

Answer (score 0):

In a simulator, make one of the resistors a small amount (1-10 %) different, and then ramp the supply --either from 0 to 12 V, or just jump it from 11 to 12 V. This will start the oscillation. In real life the supply does ramp, and also (thermal) noise would start the oscillation anyway.